# Um service do Android trava a aplicação mesmo rodando em background?

Tags: java, android, thread, android-service

Um service do Android trava a aplicação mesmo rodando em background? Ou há algo de errado na minha aplicação?

Tenho um banco de dados aonde a última tabela tem 3000 linhas. Com isso resolvi inserir em background usando uma service para dar mais rapidez para o usuário na hora da inserção. Porém este service está travando minha aplicação, e só libera a minha aplicação quando a Thread inserir todos os dados no banco.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Segue o código.

```
public class ServiceAndroid extends Service{

    Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();       

    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "iniciou o service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    //meu código
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }       
        };
        thread.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


}
```

método onde chamo o service:

```
// inicia o service
   public void startService(View view){

       Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ServiceAndroid.class);
       startService(i);
   }
```

Comment: O código me parece estar correto. Talvez você deva informar mais detalhes sobre o que há na parte "`//meu código`".

Comment: Eu não coloquei p/ facilitar a visualização, mas são apenas chamadas do método inserir, nada demais com o 'cv.put("chave", valor);'

Comment: Você está parando o serviço após a Thread terminar o trabalho? Declarou ele no Manifest?

Comment: sim declarei, não estou parando porque não precisa, depois que ele inseriu minha tabela não há o que fazer. Ele está funcionando, o problema é que ele está travando minha aplicação até inserir tudo.

Comment: Travando como? Poste a parte do código onde faz o *start* do serviço.

Comment: atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Tente explicar o comportamento da aplicação após o serviço ter sido iniciado. Você diz que ele "trava", o que quer dizer exactamente com isso?

Comment: Quando o serviço é iniciado se eu apertar algum botão ele só é acionado quando o service terminar de inserir a tabela e encerrar seu processo, e como se ele não estivesse funcionando em background.

Comment: Pelo que andei pesquisando, o service mesmo rodando em background afeta a UI Thread, o que posso fazer é colocar a Thread do service para "dormir" toda vez que a UI Thread precisar ser utilizada.